# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "brauchen" "verbrauchen" und "aufbrauchen"?

Tags: meaning

I have recently seen an exercise where I need to specify which verb to put in the sentence. The sentence was ,, Hast du meine Sonnenbrille.......? Dann hättest du mir eine neue kaufen können. "
I was hesitant between "gebrauchen" and "verbrauchen" and "aufgebrauchen". So can anyone please explain to me the differences between those meanings?

Comment: What does the dictionary say?

Comment: aber, manchmal ist ,,verbrauchen'' ,,aufbrauchen", oder?
die Luft in den Räumen ist verbraucht.
Oder, als das Geld nach einigen verbraucht war, versuchte er 1992 als ,,Dagobert" den Kaufhaus-Konzern noch einmal zu erpressen. ( Der Kriminallfall Dagobert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Brauchen** has two distinct meanings, *to need*, and *to use*:

> Hast du meine Sonnenbrille **gebraucht**? Dann hättest du mir eine neue kaufen können.

There are two ways to interpret it:

*Did you **need** my sunglasses? You could have bought me new ones, then.*

*Did you **use** my sunglasses? You could have bought me new ones, then.*

Huh? Neither of these makes sense, because neither needing nor using sunglasses will consume them. It's a tool, it stays intact after being used. No need to buy a new one.

(Northern German speakers prefer the verb *benutzen* for the latter case.)

---

Knowing that, we come to the core of the question: What's the difference between **brauchen** and **verbrauchen/aufbrauchen**?

Let's not use a tool but **consumable supplies**, e.g. *der Kaffee* (coffee):

> Hast du meinen Kaffee **gebraucht**? Dann hättest du mir neuen kaufen können.

*Did you **need/use** my coffee? You could have bought me new (coffee), then.*

The first sentence makes it clear someone needed/used your coffee, but it doesn't specify the amount. Most likely there's still coffee there. You are picky about your coffee supplies, ordering to buy a replacement for the slightest missing amount.

> Hast du meinen Kaffee **verbraucht/aufgebraucht**? Dann hättest du mir neuen kaufen können.

*Did you **consume all** my coffee? You could have bought me new (coffee), then.*

The first sentence makes it clear someone consumed **all** of your coffee supplies.

Also note you cannot use **aufbrauchen** or **verbrauchen** for the sunglasses of your original example because they aren't consumable supplies. But that's the very reason the second sentence makes no sense for sunglasses either.

---

The difference between **verbrauchen** and **aufbrauchen** is more subtle.

> Dieses Auto **verbraucht** viel Benzin.

This car **consumes** a lot of gasoline.

You cannot use *aufbrauchen* here, because it always means *to consume **all***, while *verbrauchen* can also mean *to consume*.

Answer (score 3):

Gegenstände, die durch ihre normale Benutzung weniger werden, kann man *verbrauchen*, also in ihrer Menge verringern oder *aufbrauchen*, also vollständig konsumieren.

- *Ich habe das ganze Mehl aufgebraucht, kannst du bitte neues kaufen?* Hier kann auch *verbrauchen* verwendet werden.
- *Mein Auto verbraucht 10 Liter Sprit auf 100km.* Hier kann man nicht *aufgebrauchen* verwenden, da die Benzinverbrennung ein kontinuierlicher Vorgang ist und in der Regel nach 100km noch Benzin da ist.

Gegenstände die wie Sonnenbrille, die auch durch die reguläre Benutzung erhalten bleiben, werden *gebraucht* und niemals *verbraucht* oder *aufgebraucht*. Das gilt auch, wenn der Gegenstand bei einem Gebrauch zerstört werden sollte, wie *Meine Sonnenbrille ist zerbrochen. Hast du sie gebraucht?*

*Gebrauchen* meint nicht nur die Benutzung sondern auch soviel wie *benötigen*:

- *Er hatte Mehl gebraucht, um einen Kuchen zu backen.* besagt, dass das Mehl zum Kuchenbacken notwendig war.
- *Er hatte Mehl verbraucht, um einen Kuchen zu backen.* Beim Kuchenbacken hat er Mehl verwendet, wodurch sich dessen Menge verringert hat.
- *Er hat das Mehl aufgebraucht, um einen Kuchen zu backen.* Beim Kuchenbacken hat er das gesamte Mehl verwendet und jetzt ist keins mehr da.

Im Deutschen unterscheidet man auch zwischen *Verbrauchsgegenständen* (z. B. Zucker, Mehl, Öl, Benzin, Papier, Toner) und *Gebrauchsgegenständen* (z. B. Fahrrädern, Sonnenbrillen, Stühlen).

Comment: Es gibt durchaus Randbereiche für *verbrauchen* - Gegenstände, die zwar nicht "weniger" werden, sondern "leer" - wie Batterien, z.B. Menschen können im übertragenen Sinne auch "verbraucht aussehen".

Comment: Ja, richtig. Eigentlich drückt man sich damit aber nicht ganz korrekt aus: Es wird ja nicht die Batterie (die Verpackung) sondern deren Ladung (den Inhalt) verbraucht. Man verbraucht ja auch nicht die Mehltüte sondern deren Inhalt. Bei Menschen bezieht man sich mit _verbraucht_ in der Regel auf deren Kraft oder Energie.